# Better data structure to handle this array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data get from the server(ordered by date):

`[ {date:"2012-8", name:"Tokyo"}, {date:"2012-3", name:"Beijing"}, {date:"2011-10", name:"New York"} ]`

I'd like to :

1. get the name of the first element whose date is in a given year, for example, given `2012`, I need `Tokyo`
2. get the year of a given `name`
3. change the date of a `name`

which data structure should I use to make this effective ?

because the array could be large, I prefer not to loop the array to find something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears that the data is *probably* already sorted by descending date you could use a *binary search* on that data to avoid performing a full linear scan.

To handle the *unstated* requirement that changing the date will then change the ordering, you would need to perform two searches, which as above could be binary searches.  Having found the current index, and the index where it's supposed to be, you can use two calls to `Array.splice()` to move the element from one place in the array to another.

To handle searches by name, and assuming that each `name` is unique, you should create a secondary structure that maps from names to elements:

```
var map = {};
for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var name = array[i].name;
    map[name] = array[i];
}
```

You can then use the `map` array to directly address requirements 2 and 3.

Because the `map` elements are actually just references to the `array` elements, changes to those elements will happen in both.

Comment: and when I change the date of an element, the order of the array need to change

Comment: @wong2 well that's just peachy, isn't it!  Why didn't you say so in the first place?!  And what's the order - date descending?

Comment: if you didn't keep the order, how could you `loop through the array until you find the first matching element`?

Comment: @wong2 because the only "order" that could be discerned from the question is the _implicit_ order that they were already in.  You never said anything about the order being related to the dates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using unique cities, I would use the city names as a map key:

```
cities = {
  Tokyo: {
    date: "2012-8" 
  },
  New York: {
    date: "2011-10"
  }
}
```

To search by date:

```
function byDate(date) {
  for(el in cities) {
    if(cities.hasOwnProperty(el) && cities[el].date === date)
      return el;
  }
}
```

Comment: `get the name of the first element whose date is in a given year` how to do this?

Comment: @wong2 You're still going to have to loop the structure - there is no way to simultaneously group by city and also by year without duplicating the data.

Comment: Your search by date is wrong - the `cities` object is _unordered_, whereas the OP's original data is an _array_, with an implicit ordering.

Comment: That's not in the original question, so it's not implemented here. The question was **which data structure should I use to make this effective**, and the answer is a **mapping of unique keys to data**.

Comment: It is in the question - you cannot do a search for "first matching" in a JS object because a JS object has no order.  The OP's data does.

Comment: Well now the question has been changed to signify this. I guess the OP wants the list re-sorted when the dates change too? That won't be fun with dates like `"2012-8"`

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: without redesigning your date structure you could use sorting combined with the Array `filter` or `map` method:

```
function sortByDate(a,b){
   return Number(a.date.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'')) > 
           Number(b.date.replace(/[^\d]+/g,''));
}
var example = [ {date:"2012-8", name:"Tokyo"}, 
                {date:"2012-3", name:"Beijing"}, 
                {date:"2011-10", name:"New York"} ]
              .sort(sortByDate);
//first city with year 2012 (and the lowest month of that year)
var b = example.filter(function(a){return +(a.date.substr(0,4)) === 2012})[0];
b.name; //=> Beijing
//year of a given city
var city = 'Tokyo';
var c = example.filter(function(a){return a.city === city;})[0];
c.year; //=> 2012
//change year of 'New York', and resort data
var city = 'New York', date = '2010-10';
example = example.map(
         function(a){if (a.name === city) {a.date = date;} return a;}
        ).sort(sortByDate);
```